# Can NAT Table be vulnerable toward any poisoning attacks?

Tags: network, firewalls, nat

I am learning the general concept of network security, and becomes aware of two poisoning attacks on the network infrastructures, that is, DNS poisoning attacks and ARP poisoning attacks. They are both due to certain cache structures.

It seems to me, that NAT table in the firewall is also using a cache structure to maintain the address translation. So I am just wondering whether that's also vulnerable toward certain poisoning attacks. I think the answer is no, because firewall is trustful and its cache is maintained by itself. But just want to confirm my intuition here. Thank you very much.

Comment: It is certainly possible to execute denial-of-service attacks against stateful firewalls by overloading their state table or their NAT table (although, depending on configuration, these attacks might need to come from the inside). But I don’t know about redirecting traffic with a NAT attack. Just denial of service.